# I am trying to set a new rule using PHP language

Tags: php, opencart, e-commerce, vendor

I am using Opencart have a multi-vendor E-commerce store for local delivery and vendors have the ability to set their delivery fees right from their account, I would like vendors to add their fees but it shouldn't exceed 15 S.R, so I went to the controller and tried to modify it, but it didn't work. here is my work.

I found this code:

```
    foreach ($data['rules'] as $rule) {
        // Minimum required fields for each rule
        if (empty($rule['destinations'])) {
            throw new FormDataError($this->language->get('ms_shipping_error_rule_destinations_required'));
        }

        if (!isset($rule['cost'])) {
            throw new FormDataError($this->language->get('ms_shipping_error_rule_cost_required'));
```

and then I added under it the following code:

```
        if ($rule < 15 ['cost']) {
            echo 'The cost should be 15 S.R or less';
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I am not sure what is the right way of writing this code, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The condition syntax is not correct. It should be like that:

```
if ($rule['cost'] <= 15) {
    echo 'The cost should be 15 S.R or less';
}
```

But it would be nice to throw an exception instead of just echoing some message.

Comment: That's right, thank you for your help, but I am still able to put more than 15 S.R, also the page doesn't get refresh when I hit the save button. Do you think is the code missing something?

Comment: It also depends on your form inputs. If it's array input like `name="cost[]"` then your condition should be like that `if (array_sum($rule['cost']) <= 15) { /* your code here*/ }`

This example means that the total amounts should not be more than 15. If you want to check the biggest cost should not be more than 15 then you just need to do it like that: ``if (max($rule['cost']) <= 15) { /* your code here*/ }`

Btw, if it should not be 15 then you need to use `<` as in your code instead of `<=`.